# MergeSort Algorithm combined with Elo Rating System and 2AFC

Tags: mergesort

I wanted to inquire today about the best way to code/approach the following problem:

Combining the A+C Strategy of the three 2AFC Methods with an ELO rating system, and in this case we will be referring to the variables being compared as "items." The researcher knows which are positive and which are negative, but not the observer. 'A' refers to the comparing of known positives against known negatives. 'C' is the later comparing of items that ended part 'A' with similar ELO ratings during A's initial comparing. Examples of this is that an observer makes 5 comparisons, which uses 10 images (if using the 2AFC method), and if the item is chosen as positive it gets +1 pts while the negative gets -1 pts, and a tie gives 0.5 to both items.

I was thinking around four to five rounds of using the 'A' method comparisons would be enough to give sufficient data of where each item used should be ranked somewhat accurately among the others. Then to move on and compare using C's method, I wanted to ask what a good indicator of when to stop the comparing with this method would be and to return the combined array of ranked images.

I want advice as to the best way to approach this and even some testing code if that would not be a bother at all.